# logstash not fast enough output to elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I use logstash as indexer to output data into elasticsearch from redis, but it is not fast enougth because of large data. And then I used mutil workers,but it will be lead various problem. There are other better ways to do faster output? Thanks.

Here is my configuration:

```
input {
  redis {
    host => "10.240.93.41"
    data_type => "list"
    key => "tcpflow"
  }
}
filter {
  csv {
    columns => [ts,node,clientip,vip,rtt,city,isp,asn,province]
    separator => "|"
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    index => "tcpflow-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    index_type => "tcpflow"
    cluster => "elasticsearch"
    host => ["10.240.93.41", "10.240.129.32"]
    #protocol => "node"
    #protocol => "http"
    #port => 8200
    protocol => "transport"
    manage_template => false
    workers => 30
  }
}
```

Comment: whats the size of an output event? You mentioned having multiple workers is causing problems for you - can you elaborate more?

Comment: I don't have a specific measured size, but if I use 5 workers will be not enougth.I just want to know is there a better way to faster.Use a lot of workers will open more files which the os hava a limit value.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The redis{} input in logstash defaults to reading one document at a time.  Try setting batch_count to something in the 100-1000 range, depending on the size of your documents.

Having multiple worker threads ("-w") is ideal, unless you're using the multiline{} filter which is not thread-safe.

Comment: Thanks. I had tried. The batch_count seems no more effect,but use "-w" is better.And it is 2000msg/sec,are there other ways to make it faster?